# Azure Appservice URL is getting messed up on deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an .NET Core MVC service that is working correctly in development

When I deploy it to Azure the url of the service is somehow getting 'https' embeeded before the route to the controller method like so

```
https://test1-ddd-dataexplorer-appsvc.azurewebsites.nethttps/dataexplorer/search
```

I am expecting just /dataexplorer/search at the end of the webservice url.

Not sure how this is being appended

Comment: As usual, it wont add https in the middle of the url. Please show how do you deploy your webapp.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you attempting to redirect the URL via Application Gateway to a relative path?  Perhaps, you have redirection configured on your app service. You can add just a trailing slash to the request.

Comment: Just deploying the web service directly from Visual Studio.  Not using any App gateway

Answer (score 0):

I had this in my startup

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
            {
                    swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer>() { new OpenApiServer { Url = httpReq.Scheme } };
            });
        });
```

which was a copy and paste from an old .NET Core 2.2 project.

Once I changed it to app.UseSwagger(); it was all good